# Evolving a matrix using a genetic algorithm

Tags: matrix, mathematical-optimization, genetic-algorithm

I recently discovered genetic algothims and after doing a little research I can't find any example on how to evolve structures more complex than a vector or a string. 
Let's say that I'm using a covariance matrix for a certain computation (to compute a mahalanobis distance for example) and I want to look for a better matrix to do the job and linimize a certain criteria, are there any classic examples on how to evolve the matrix and which crossover operators to use ?

Thanks !

Comment: A symmetric matrix can be represented as a vector (for instance by reading row by row through the upper triangular portion of the matrix). Then you can use standard vector-based representations.

Comment: You could represent the covariance matrix in factored form, eg C=L*L' for lower triangular L and evolve L. That way you would guarantee that your matrix was symmetric positive (semi) definite.

Comment: What would be your stop condition for your matrix ?

Comment: @Totem Let's say that I use the mahlanobis distance in a condition A and that I have enough data to estimate a full cov matric. For a set of new vectors corresponding to a different condition B, I want to adapt my old covariance matrix so it minimizes the distance between all B vectors. The goal is to improve the distance between a set of vectors to a certain threashold (kind of an adaptation of the covariance matrix so it could be used on few new data coming from a different setup (to overcome the problem of not having enough data to build a whole new cov matrix corresponding to condition B))

Comment: Also, related to genetic algorithms (but different) are [evolution strategies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolution_strategy). I personally like them better for continuos spaces, and tend to use GAs for discrete spaces.

Comment: Also, don't worry about a crossover operator.  You don't need it for GA. Just use mutation.

Comment: @dmuir Does this make sense, though? In principle we can do this, but then the links between L and the objective function will be much more indirect (compared with links between C and objective function). For example, C1=L1*L1' and C2=L12*L2' give decent objective values, so we choose them to breed. Presumably, crossovering C1 and C2 will give a decent C3 as well, but I double crossovering L1 and L2 to produce L3 and then computing C3 will give us good results. What do you think? Thank you very much!

Comment: @Sibbs Well as long as the diagonal elements are positive, for a given C there is a unique lower triangular L such that C = L*L', so in a sense the relationship is just as direct.

Comment: @dmuir it's good to know the lower triangular L is unique. Thanks! But still, C1=L1*L1' and C2=L12*L2' give decent objective values, so we choose them to breed. Presumably, crossovering C1 and C2 will give a decent C3 as well, but I double crossovering L1 and L2 to produce L3 and then computing C3 will give us good results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any structure of fixed size and shape that is made of numbers (or any other elements) can be rewritten to a 1-D vector and back. You can then use any operator you like which works on vectors.

If you wanted to work with matrices (or any other structures) directly you can always design your own operators, but a matrix basically **is** a vector, just written in a different way. For the matrix case there are a number of possibilites of operators (crossover):

- Swap rows/columns (between the parents)
- Swap submatrices (generalization of the above)
- Continuous-space crossover methos like BLX-alpha, PCX, arithmetic crossover... These all are designed for vectors but you will just treat the matrix as a vector (it's really not that different).

Mutation is probably going to be more or less identical to the vector-like - you just mutate the elements (or some of them).

Comment: Do you have an idea of the range of the expected values ? Or their type ? If yes, you can add random number in the range (may depend on the position) as another crossover operator to this (great) algorithm by @jan-Žegklitz.

Comment: @Totem That sounds to me more like a mutation. In crossover you combine two or more solutions together. But typical continuous-space mutation is adding a random number drawn from a normal distribution. But your operator is also used (either add a number or replace with a number).